# how can timing a function in node js to work every 6 hours Depending on the real time he has and not the time in his Device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

```
var time= new Date().getHours();

if(time== "6"){
       //function Do stuff
}
if(time== "12"){
       //function Do stuff
}
if(time== "18"){
       //function Do stuff
}
if(time== "24"){
       //function Do stuff
}
```

> but when change time in my lab to any of these hours the function call
>
> how can to get real time in his zone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the node schedule library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob("*/6 * * *", function() {
     //function Do stuff every 6 hours
});
```

Cron job format

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23) 
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Alternatively a more verbose method

```
schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 6, minute: 0, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){
   //function Do stuff every 6 hours
});
```